# How to Draw lines using wz_jsgraphics.js library in IE 7/8/9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using wz_jsgraphics.js library to draw lines. It is working with all browser other than IE 7/8/9. Now I want to run it on any IE7/8/9 browser. Please guide me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Elegant solution here: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1):

Walter Zorn's wz_jsgraphics.js works fine in IE7, IE8, and IE9 when I use these browsers on four different computers.

Internet Explorer has quite many options. Maybe one of them needs to be changed on your computer. For instance, if you are running jsgraphics offline from an html document on a file, the advanced IE option Allow Active Content To Run From A File (or whatever it is called) must, of course, be checked.